# "input cannot be resolved" when added a try..catch

Tags: java

I originally tried to get my throw statement to work without a try catch and the `userInput = input.nextInt();` line worked fine. But when I tried adding the try..catch it didn't like my input saying it cannot be resolved. I don't think my try..catch is correct yet but I am planning on tackling that after I can get this input to be recognized but I would appreciate any feedback on things you see with that as well.

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Program6 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            final int NUMBER_HIGH_LIMIT = 100;
            final int NUMBER_LOW_LIMIT = 10;
            int userInput;

            try
            {
                System.out.print("Enter a number between 10 and 100: ");
                userInput = input.nextInt();//Says input cannot be resolved

                Verify v = new Verify(NUMBER_HIGH_LIMIT, NUMBER_LOW_LIMIT);
            }
            catch(NumberHighException exception)
            {
                userInput = 0;
            }
            catch(NumberLowException exception) 
            {
                userInput = 0;  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: variables needs to be declared before you can use them in Java.

Comment: It could be that he accidentally deleted the line with the declaration when he added the try/catch.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a scanner called `input`:

```
public class Program6 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUMBER_HIGH_LIMIT = 100;
    final int NUMBER_LOW_LIMIT = 10;
    int userInput;

    try {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a number between 10 and 100: ");
      userInput = input.nextInt();//Says input cannot be resolved

      Verify v = new Verify(NUMBER_HIGH_LIMIT, NUMBER_LOW_LIMIT);

    } catch (NumberHighException exception) {
      userInput = 0;
    } catch (NumberLowException exception) {
      userInput = 0;
    }
  }
}
```